# safari binarycookies export to txt

Tags: cookies, safari

Could you recommend some tool for Windows or Unix that allows to export to txt safari cookies in binarycookies format?

If such exists, what does it require? How to run it?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a gist here: [MacRuby script to export Safari 5.1 cookies to a human-readable format](https://gist.github.com/sgonyea/1385008).  Also the exporting part is compatible with my Safari 6.0.3 on OS X 10.8.3.  It needs macruby installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to Xcode you can also compile the following Swift command line utility. I used to export cookies for use with CURL and youtube-dl: https://github.com/aseidlitz/CookieExporter